# Resizing images with Perls Image::Magick in foreach loop is too slow

Tags: perl, imagemagick

With Image:Magick from cpan I'm resizing a set of images with foreach:

```
use Image::Magick;
my @files = split(',', $cgi->param("img"));

foreach my $file (@files) {
    # do something
    my $image = Image::Magick->new;
    my $x = $image->Read($file );
        my ($width, $height, $size, $format) = $image->Ping($file);
        my $dimension;
        if ($width > $height) {
            $dimension = 'x1500';
        } else {
            $dimension = '1500x';
        }       
        $x = $image->Resize(geometry=>$dimension);
            warn "$x" if "$x";
        $x = $image->Write($destination);
            warn "$x" if "$x";
        undef $image;
}
```

This will correctly resize the images. But thats takes a long time. Is there a way to speed up this process?

Comment: Do you have a multi-core CPU? If so, you could consider parallelising with multiple threads.

Comment: You can consider switching to [Imager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager), which should be way faster than Image::Magic.

Comment: A word on your code, the `undef $image` is not needed. Your `my $image` is lexical within the loop and will go out of scope anyway.

Comment: You could consider using `libvips` which is extremely fast and less demanding on memory than ImageMagick. For example, to resize a 6000x4000 pixel jpeg to 1500px takes 1.7s with ImageMagick on my iMac, but 0.4s with `VipsThumbnail -s 1500 input.jpg`